# Weird spam of characters 61R;61R;

Tags: terminal, special-characters

Not really sure what happened cause I just left it while it was already done downloading and was in the middle of installing phase.

So I would like to ask if anyone else has experienced this for me to know what's up with this.

As for the command I ran, it's:

```
flatpak -y --user install --from https://files.kube-project.com/flatpak/com.kubeproject.kube.flatpakref
```

[image: Weird]

Comment: Seems unrelated. ANSI colour codes? Bad configured terminal? Write reset or logout and log back in. It will fix it. It is no use to obssess about this situations unless they are permanent

Comment: Seems like a possible packaging bug. If you want, report it to whoever created the package, but be advised that they might regard it as a non-critical issue.

Comment: It seems there's simply too many possibilities to know exactly what caused this but I suppose I'll try to probe from time to time and see if someone else encountered this problem. Thank you all for your valuable feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% printf '\e[6n' | console-decode-ecma48
DSR 6
% printf '\e[6n' ; console-decode-ecma48
^[[27;1R
CPR 27;1
LF
%
```

At some point something on your system wrote the control sequence that requests a device status report #6 to your terminal, over and over.  Your terminal dutifully replied with the requested report (a Cursor Position Report, CPR) over and over.  Whatever was parsing the input at that point was not a complete and correct ECMA-48 parser, and only parsed the first three/four characters of the CPR sequence, erroneously treating the rest as echoed ordinary input, as you can see.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444270/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499139/5132

Comment: Thank you very much for this wonderful answer with sources to expand learning upon. I learned something new today!