# How to bind a key combination to null in .inputrc?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, readline, inputrc

You can bind keys like <kbd>Ctrl-Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-Right</kbd> in `.inputrc` like this:

```
# Ctrl-Left
"\033[1;5D": backward-word
# Ctrl-Right
"\033[1;5C": forward-word
```

How would I bind <kbd>Ctrl-Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-Down</kbd> to nothing?

```
# Ctrl-Up
"\033[1;5A": null
# Ctrl-Down
"\033[1;5B": null
```

This obviously does not work.

I use these keys for doing stuff in tmux (nested configuration), but often `;3~` gets output into the terminal when I use either of the keys.

I'm hoping that I will be able to bind them to nothing while still having the keys work for tmux.

Comment: Of course the root cause of the problem is that GNU Readline does not have a proper ECMA-48 parser (c.f. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523308/5132 and its further reading).  But how to do a no-op in Readline is a valid question in its own right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind them to `redraw-current-line`.

Comment: of course, in `bash` you can use `bind -x` with an empty script (`bind -x '"\033[1;5D":'`), but I assume that the Q is about `readline` in general.

Comment: There is `nop`. But unbinding is the correct thing to do, see @paradroid's answer.

Comment: Where is `nop`?

Comment: I always thought it was a thing, but it appears that binding to any undefined function name has the same effect.  `"\e=":` is bound to `possible-completions` by default. Putting any of the lines `"\e=":`,`"\e=": nop`, `"\e=": foobar` results in `bind -p | fgrep '"\e='` printing nothing (And `M-=` does not do anything). It appears either RL or bash is permissive: no diagnostics, no nothing. Sorry I was misleading you. In fact, `"\e=":` w/o arguments unbinds the key just fine.

Comment: @kkm-stillwaryofSEpromises  It seems this works for simple key sequences involving 1 Ctrl or escape. For sequences with both, running e.g. `bind '"\e\C-f":'` on the command line reliably unbinds the sequence from shell-forward-word, but does not work in inputrc. It seems like a bug.

Comment: @SpinUp__ADavis Thanks, interesting. I'll try to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I found that another option is to use double quotation marks.

```
# Ctrl-Up
"\033[1;5A": ""
# Ctrl-Down
"\033[1;5B": ""
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. This difference is important when the bound key is also prefix to a multi-key sequence: if the head key is not bound, readline waits for the second key indefinitely; if it's bound, only for a short timeout.

Comment: This is not quite the same as unbinding the key -- this actually binds it to an empty macro, which may or may not work for a particular application. You can see the macros using `bind -s`.